# json_encode only returns the first element of an array?

Tags: php, json

I am using json_encode to create a JSON object from an array.  They array is a couple hundred elements long, but json_encode appears to only give back the first element of the array.

Is this a limitation of json_decode, or am I using the wrong syntax to read the JSON object?

A little code:
I create the array in PHP:

```
$getarrayforjson = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

And in the javascript, I made it a variable:

```
var my_array = <?php echo json_encode($getarrayforjson); ?>
```

Typing 'my_array' in the console gives me a nice JSON-looking response, but only for the first element.

When I use the JSON in the code, like my_array.title, or my_array[4], I always get the same result.

I think my syntax is wrong, but am not sure how to fix it. I'm new to using json_encode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$getarrayforjson = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

That *is* only one result. Try this:

```
<?php
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
    $json[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode( $json );
```

Comment: also add MYSQL_ASSOC to the mysql_fetch_array()

Comment: Berry, thank you for the quick and correct answer! To finish the thought, I then get the titles out of the JSON object like this: `my_array[settings.activeImage].title`. This lets me add a title from my database to each image in a lightbox.(There may be an easier way to do that, but this worked.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `print_r()` or `print()` instead of `echo`.

`var my_array = <?php print_r(json_encode($getarrayforjson)); ?>`

I've run into this issue myself and it has confused me as well. `json_encode()` returns a string and as such I'd expect `echo` would return the entire string to be decoded, but in some instances it does not.